# How should I host the website on firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

after calling `firebase init` in vs code terminal, then opting `Hosting`, then opting to choose the existing projects

i am facing the below error

```
Error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
```

how should i resolve it?
firebase log file

```
 at Client.doRequest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/apiv2.js:209:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Client.request (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/apiv2.js:96:20)
    at async getProjectPage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/management/projects.js:233:17)
    at async getFirebaseProjectPage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/management/projects.js:250:23)
    at async selectProjectInteractively (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/management/projects.js:95:41)
    at async Object.doSetup [as project] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/init/features/project.js:87:27)
    at async init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/init/index.js:19:9)
[error] 
[error] Error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
```

please guide

Comment: Did you check `firebase-debug.log` as the error message says? What was in that file?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have added the firebase log in the question and login is done

Comment: If `firebase login --reauth` isn't working, try `firebase logout` and then `firebase login`.

Comment: @samthecodingman the login is successful now but not able to get the list of the projects in the firebase, I have updated the question with the `firebase-debug.log` , please help me according to that. thanks

Comment: Make sure you've logged in with the correct Google account, are running the latest `npm i -g firebase-tools` version and that the account you are using has the correct permissions on that project.